# Indenting lists in HTML

Tags: html, list, indentation

I am trying to make a webpage and I came across a probmem–Indenting a list.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

[image: Final product]

But I cant quite figure out how to indent the numbered list. Using my code, this is what it looks like

[image: What My image looks like]

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Top Five Cat & Dog Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Top Five Cat & Dog Names</h1>
    <h2>Top Five Cat Names</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Female Cats</li>
    </ul>
        <ol>
            <li>Tigger</li>
            <li>Tiger</li>
            <li>Smokey</li>
            <li>Kitty</li>
            <li>Sassy</li>
        </ol>
    <ul>
</body>
```

the code continues, but I need to get this issue resolved first

Thanks for any help! =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to do this, believe it or not, is to actually put the ordered list inside the "Female Cats" `<li>`. This is the most semantic way to achieve this, as it tells browsers and web crawlers (such as Google) that the second list is actually a *child* of the parent list. This is important for search indexing, among other things.

Here is how you should do it. If you want extra vertical space between the lists, fiddle around with the CSS of the ordered list.

```html
<h1>Top Five Cat &amp; Dog Names</h1>
<h2>Top Five Cat Names</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Female Cats
        <ol>
            <li>Tigger</li>
            <li>Tiger</li>
            <li>Smokey</li>
            <li>Kitty</li>
            <li>Sassy</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Male Cats
        <ol>
            <li>Figaro</li>
            <li>Tom</li>
            <li>Ahkmenrah</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `<ol>` a left margin:

```css
ol {
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Top Five Cat & Dog Names</h1>

 <h2>Top Five Cat Names</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Female Cats</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>Tigger</li>
    <li>Tiger</li>
    <li>Smokey</li>
    <li>Kitty</li>
    <li>Sassy</li>
</ol>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS set the

```
 ol{
     margin-left:
 }
```

to whatever you want